# Problemas con Geolocalización en html5

Tags: javascript, html5

Mi problema es que no me muestra **la latitud y la longitud** .
Si me genera el mensaje de permiso, pero cuando presiono: acepto, no me muestra nada. lo estoy trabajando desde local y con la ultima versión de google chrome actualizada.*(por cierto estoy con Internet)*

*Aqui les adjunto el código que estoy utilizando:*

```js
var x = document.getElementById("ubicacion");
function myUbicacion() { 
       navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
}

function showPosition(position) {  
 x.innerHTML = "Latitud: " + position.coords.latitude +"<br>Longitud: " + position.coords.longitude;
}
```

```html
<button  onclick="myUbicacion()">Mi ubicacion</button>
<p  id="ubicacion"></p>
```

Comment: El código que has mandado es correcto. A mi me funciona metiendo la función de JavaScript dentro del mismo html. Mira bien si esta bien redirigido si lo tienes en un fichero externo. Sino pon la función en el mismo html y veras que funciona. Si necesitas algo mas dime. Un saludo.

Comment: @GonzaloRodriguez el código lo tengo dentro de mi html, la verdad se me hace raro que no me muestre el resultado. estaba pensado que tal vez sea por el antivirus pero al parecer no es eso.

Comment: Has probado en otro navegador?

Comment: si, he probado con firefox,Internet explorer;y no me muestra la latitud ni longitud, sospeche que tal vez sea por el firewall de windows y lo desactive pero al parecer no es eso tampoco. La verdad no se que otra cosa podría ser :(

Comment: Mira bien los permisos que tiene tu pagina. A lo mejor esta bloqueando el acceso a tu ubicación.

Comment: Si, ya los revise, tengo activado el Javascript en mis navegadores y los permisos están bien es muy raro esto . pero seguiré intentando en buscar la solución.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo reajuste de esta forma y me mostró los resultados de longitud y latitud al parecer estaba realizando mal las llamadas a la función. y pues sobre el problema del navegador no tenia nada que ver, era error de código al parecer.

```js
function myUbicacion(){ 
var x = document.getElementById("ubicacion");
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);

function showPosition(position) {  
  x.innerHTML = "Latitud: " + position.coords.latitude +"<br>Longitud: " + position.coords.longitude+"";
}
}
```

```html
<button  onclick="myUbicacion()">Mi localizacion</button>
<p id="ubicacion" ></p>
```